# How to check when connectionDidFinishLoading finishes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, class, while-loop

I have set up a simple Objective-C class in my iOS app which has one simple task, to download a JSON file, parse it and then pass back a NSString which contains a variable parsed from the downloaded JSON file.

The problem I have is that I am calling this class from another class and this all works great however I need to pass back the NSString to the class from which I am calling it from.

The problem is that the method passes back the empty NSString BEFORE connectionDidFinishLoading happens.... And so the NSString never gets assigned a string......

I have setup a while loop in my method but it doesn't really work.....

here is my code:

```
-(NSString *)get_user_icon:(NSString *)YT_ID {

// Set BOOL to 0 for initial setup.
icon_check = 0;

NSString *url_YT = [NSString stringWithFormat:YOUT_profile_part_2, YT_ID];

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Icon downloader YouTube", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSURLRequest *theRequest_YT = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_YT]];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection_YT = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest_YT delegate:self];

        if (theConnection_YT) {
            YT_JSON_FEED = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"Respoce happening...");
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"failed");
        }
    });
});

while (icon_check == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Wait");
}

return icon_url;
}

/// Data loading ///

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [YT_JSON_FEED setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [YT_JSON_FEED appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed: %@", [error description]];
    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *feed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:YT_JSON_FEED options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

icon_url = [[[[[feed objectForKey:@"items"] valueForKey:@"snippet"] valueForKey:@"thumbnails"] valueForKey:@"default"] valueForKey:@"url"];

icon_check = 1;
}
```

Comment: Do NOT "check". Set up your delegate, you will be TOLD when the download is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a synchronous request (blocking until there is something to return), use `NSURLConnection`'s `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` instead. Like so:

```
-(NSString *)get_user_icon:(NSString *)YT_ID {

    NSString *url_YT = [NSString stringWithFormat:YOUT_profile_part_2, YT_ID];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest_YT = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_YT]];

    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest_YT returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    //Check response and error for possible errors here.

    //If no errors.
    NSDictionary *feed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    icon_url = [[[[[feed objectForKey:@"items"] valueForKey:@"snippet"] valueForKey:@"thumbnails"] valueForKey:@"default"] valueForKey:@"url"];

    return icon_url;
}
```

However this is not recommended. You need to change your API to be asynchronous. Either delegate-based, but more preferably, using block-based API.

Comment: Thank you for you're help and explanation. I will look into using block based API too.